# app crash on back button pressed

Tags: iphone, crash

in my app i have 2 views
**view1**

```
{  
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2Controoler animated:YES];

}
```

**view2**
here when i am pressing back button app is crash without error or warning
also in **view2** i am using following code

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory ];
```

in xcode last statement shows the warning "`directoryContentsAtPath` is depricated" so i try to use

```
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
```

and this statement shows "`NSFileManager` may not respond to `directoryContentsAtPath:error`" anyways still I tried to run app and

app crashed with Exception "reason: '-`[NSFileManager directoryContentsAtPath:error:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6302f50'"

I hope some one know how to solve this issue

Thank you

"

Comment: hey pooja what actually you are doing in view2?

Comment: I just wanted to display data in table format nothing else and user can go back by using back button...but every time app crashes on pressing back button

Comment: its strange because I have so many views in my app but they are working perfectly with back button

Comment: it means. something wrong in viewwillappear of view1. when you hit back put the debugging point in view1's viewwillapper method. you will found the problem.

Comment: but what i m saying put the debugging point in the view1's viewwillapper method. so u will get the errored line.

Comment: yes you are right its problem in view1

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions, its so simple i must do debugging 1st anyways thanks a lot

Comment: you welcome :) Debugging is the best way to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager has no class methods other than `+defaultManager`. You should be using `– contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` with your instance of a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think `directoryContentsAtPath:` returns an autoreleased object.

If you have directoryContent set up as a `@property(nonatomic, retain)` in your header you can set it using

`self.directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: documentsDirectory];`

and it will automatically retain the object returned by `NSFileManager`, otherwise you could call

`directoryContent = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: documentsDirectory] retain];`

but be sure to release that object when you no longer need it.

[From Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

```
directoryContentsAtPath:
Returns the directories and files (including symbolic links) contained in a given directory. (Deprecated in iOS 2.0. Use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: instead.)

- (NSArray *)directoryContentsAtPath:(NSString *)path
```

[From Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) Suggest you to use

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```